# Check for a string in if-statement

Tags: python, string, input, int

I have a program with some user inputs and I need to check if what the user entered was a string or an integer value between 1 and 10 million.

My code looks like this (simplified):

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a value between 1 and 10 million: ")
    if inp < 1:
        print "Must be higher than 1"
        continue
    elif inp > 10.000.000:
        print "Must be less than 10.000.000"
        continue
    elif 'inp is a string':                           #here's my problem
        print "Must be an integer value!"
        continue
    else:
        'execute the rest of the code'
```

I don't know how to solve this. My program always terminates when I enter a string by mistake.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't name a variable ``in``. It's a reserved word in Python.

Comment: It was just an abbreviation for input from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using Python 2, which will happily compare strings to integers. You don't want to do that. Secondly, `raw_input()` will *always* return a string. What you're hoping to do is check if that string could possibly *represent* a number. Third, `10.000.000` is improper syntax. Don't use separators. Fourth, you only need to `continue` if you want to go to the top of the loop *early*. If everything's in an `if..elif..else` block at the end of the loop, only one of those will be executed, so you don't need to put a `continue` at the end of each branch. You can use `continue` statements or restructure your branch. Finally, don't use `in` as a variable name, because that's a Python keyword.

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a value between 1 and 10 million: ")

    if not inp.isdigit():
        print "Must be an integer value!"
        continue # each of these continue statements acts like a "failed, try again"

    inp = int(inp)

    if inp < 1:
        print "Must be higher than 1"
        continue # same for this one

    if inp > 10000000:
        print "Must be less than 10.000.000"
        continue # and this one

    # execute the rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot. That's what I was looking for! And simplified the code to be readable more easily therefore I used the sperators :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.isdigit()` to check if string consists of numbers to make sure it can be convertible to integer:

```
while True:
    in = raw_input("Enter a value between 1 and 10 million: ")
    if in.isdigit():
        number = int(in)
        if number < 1:
            print "Must be higher than 1"
            continue
        elif number > 10**6:
            print "Must be less than 10.000.000"
            continue
       else:
           'execute the rest of the code'
    else:
        print "Must be an integer value!"
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you I used Tigerhawk's version of .isdigit()

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you came up with your code but here are different suggestions:

Don't use "in" as variable name because it's a python operator.

After the input you can check whether it is an int or a string.

Your program can look like this:

```
while True:    
    try:
        input_int = int(raw_input("Enter a value between 1 and 10 million: "))
        if  input_int < 1 :
            print "Must be higher than 1"
        elif input_int > 10**7:
            print "Must be less than 10.000.000"
    except:
        print "Must be an integer value!"
    else: #You can use else with try/except block
        #'execute the rest of the code'
```

Voilà

Comment: I don't know how I missed the `in`, but there you have it.

Comment: However, I wouldn't recommend a name of `input`, either, as that's a built-in function (in Python 2 as well as 3).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but Tigers version helped me first.